# Grease pencil layers cant merged keeping mask

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, masking, layers

Testing around the grease pencil on 2.9 and notice that there s no "keeping alpha" option on the layers, so no choice but using mask. However when the layers are merged the mask effects are not kept......

is there a way to merge 2 layers while keeping the mask effects?
or
a way to draw while keeping the layers alpha?

or its really well hidden I cant find it huuuuuuhhh

Comment: I wouldn't imagine it's possible to keep the mask effects after merging layers because the layer order and the layer names are essential factors in setting up the mask effect from the start.